# All uploaded files are not displayed in the links

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have written as

```
 protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpFileCollection fileCollection = Request.Files;
        for (int i = 0; i < fileCollection.Count; i++)
        {
            HttpPostedFile uploadfile = fileCollection[i];
            string fileName = Path.GetFileName(uploadfile.FileName);
            if (uploadfile.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                uploadfile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/UploadFiles/") + fileName);
                 lblMessage.Text += fileName + "Saved Successfully<br>";
                 hyperlnk.Text = fileName.ToString() + "Saved Successfully<br>";
               // hyperlnk.Attributes.Add("href", Server.MapPath("/UploadFiles/") + fileName);
                 hyperlnk.NavigateUrl="~/UploadFiles/" + fileName;
                //lblMessage.Text= "<a href=" + "/UploadFiles/" + fileName +">"+fileName+"</a>";
            }
        }
    }
```

When we Upload multiple files, only one of them is displayed in link as shown in screenshot
[image]

Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add panel of type Panel on the page instead of hyperlnk and use it for a container for your links the code will look like following:

```
panel.Controls.Clear();
for (int i = 0; i < fileCollection.Count; i++)
{
    HttpPostedFile uploadfile = fileCollection[i];
    string fileName = Path.GetFileName(uploadfile.FileName);
    if (uploadfile.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        uploadfile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/UploadFiles/") + fileName);
        lblMessage.Text += fileName + "Saved Successfully<br>";
        HyperLink dynamHyperLink = new HyperLink();
        dynamHyperLink.Text = fileName.ToString() + "Saved Successfully<br>";
        // hyperlnk.Attributes.Add("href", Server.MapPath("/UploadFiles/") + fileName);
        dynamHyperLink.NavigateUrl = "~/UploadFiles/" + fileName;

        panel.Controls.Add(dynamHyperLink);
        //lblMessage.Text= "<a href=" + "/UploadFiles/" + fileName +">"+fileName+"</a>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, the following approach is not a good design, it is a better to combine a collection of data objects and bind it to the some list control (at least to Repeater)

Answer (score 1):

You appear to have a single hyperlink object, accessed via a variable called `hyperlnk`.

If you want to have multiple links, you'll need to create multiple links.

(You can see all the label text, because you're *appending* to the label text on each iteration of the loop, whereas you're *replacing* the hyperlink text/url. You can't just append to the hyperlink, because you want to have several independent links.)

Comment: I am not getting this

Comment: How should I create multiple links.. Please provide code

Comment: @Nida: Well think about the collection of controls you need, and add more `HyperLink` objects to the controls within your page... (I'm not just going to give you code - you need to *think* about it.)

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to create 1 hyperlink at each iteration, instead off assigning a different value to that same hyperlink on each iteration.

E.g.:

```
for (int i = 0; i < fileCollection.Count; i++)
        {
             HyperLink link = new HyperLink();
             link.Text = "whatever";

             form1.Controls.Add(link);
        }
```

I would expand on this example by adding necessary code for displaying the link but I am not well-versed in Web Forms.